# Java problema para un usuario pueda ingresar un arreglo char

Tags: java, jframe, scanner

Venia a preguntar ¿cómo puedo insertar los valores de un arreglo en esa parte?

```
char cadena[] = {a,a,a,b,a,a,a,a,0, 1};
```

Ya sea para que lo escanee en la consola, o bien para usarlo en un `jframe`, pero que quede exactamente como esta declarado en el código.

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char a = 2;
    char b = 3;

    char cadena[] = {a,a,a,b,a,a,a,a,0, 1};

    System.out.println("Tu cadena ingresada fue: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(cadena[i] + ",");
    }

    int inicio = 0;
    int aceptacion = 4;
    int estado = inicio;
    boolean fin = false;
    int contador = 0;
    System.out.println("\n\nEmpezamos con contador " + contador);
    while (fin == false) {
        if (contador > cadena.length - 1) {
            System.out.println("\n\nTerminamos en el estado: " + estado
                    + "\nCon un numero de transiciones: " + contador
                    + "\nEstado de aceptacion: " + aceptacion
                    + "\nEstado inicial: " + inicio
                    + "\nCon el largo de cadena: " + cadena.length);
            fin = true;
            break;
        }


    if (estado == aceptacion) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\nLa cadena si pertence a la expresion regular");
    } else {

        System.out.println("La cadena no pertenece a la expresion regular");
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes explicar mejor lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Has intentado algo hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar este codigo para solicitar los valores graficamente y luego el resultado que es un `String` puedes usar un `Split` para separa el contenido adecuadamente y convertirlos en un arreglo.

```
String texto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(new JFrame(), "Ingrese los valores?");
```

ahora lo separas:

```
String cadena[] = texto.split(","); //aqui uso el separador
```